# What does the community think about asking (and answering) really simple questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I've got a few family members that are, well let's just say "not very technologically astute", and have asked me a few times similar questions on how to use different online services that most people would find "very easy" to do.  I was wondering what the community thought about me asking and answering some of these question on the site and then referring my family members to these questions.  (These would be similar to the [community-faq](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq) that SuperUser has)

Here's an example question I received today:

- How do I update a contact's email address in Outlook.com?

The way that I see it, this is a valid (albeit very simple) question that other people may actually not know how to do.  What do you think?  What should we/I do with questions like this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with asking and answering simple questions - after all they're only simple if you know the answer.

If you don't know the right terms to search for then no amount of Googling is going to help.

It's also worth posting if you have to go through several links or wizards to get to the answer or it is buried somewhere in the depths of a site.

However, as Lohris points out, if a search using the terms you do know brings up the right answer then there's probably no point in posting a question in the first place.

Comment: On the other hand, if googling with the terms you _do_ know brings the results, you should have tried that first, and the question should be removed.

Comment: @Lohoris - That was the assumption behind my answer!