# Let's make "research efforts" more specific: request to search the web app help

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Please see [As of today, April 2023, what do we understad that it's our intended audience and what is the first that we tell them about how to participate?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5012/88163)

---

## Overview

Please bear with me. This post is not about a policy change. This clarification is done as this post has being referred in other posts. Readers comming here without the proper context, due to the way that this post was referred might be biased interpretation. Inmediately below there is an explanation of the original intention of this post, below is the orignal content that might be edited later to address several concerns.

### Purpose of this post

While it's true that the tooltips of the upvote / downvote use the term "research effort" this term was used as shorthand to refer to a set of the oldest core rules. This oldest rules have synthetised in the help article [Why do I see a message that my question does not meet quality standards?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).

The spirit of "research effort" is actually about question be good fit according to topicality and audience. Users that are unfamiliar, before asking a question might have to spend time getting familiar with the topic in order to be able to write a question properly.

In the specific case of Web Applications Stack Exchange people that are new to using a web application should spend time getting familiar with it before asking the question.

Another particular circumstance of Web Applications Stack Exchange is that the site scope is way too broad. While in other sites might be *core community* have developed a shared understanding that allows them with very few words communicate clearly between them, Web Applications hasn't such *core community*, so askers should write their questions to address a broad audience and write questions that serve as example of good questions.

This site was the first site created from an Area 51 proposal in 2010. Many things have changed since then, i.e., there was certain urgence to a low of new questions that help to clearly define the scope of this site. Nowadays the most urgent need considering the lack of a *core community* and the very low participation in moderating the site that askers have better guidance about how to ask a good question.

This post focus in one element related to asking a good question, the previous work or the fix of the lack of such such work that usually is referred as **research effort**.

Again, this is not about site scope or moderation policies. This is about providing guidance to question askers.

The below wording use the word *required* between quotes, as was said above, there is no policy change, what was tried to say is that the guidance will emphatically suggest that people should prepare theirself before asking the question and show that the understand what is being asked. A web application beginner usually might need a more operative instruction, something short and direct. As all the big web applications nowadays include resources for end-users available online, it makes perfectly sense to point them to these resources instead of asking them to "google", first because the introductory resources will help them to understand the web application features and the elemental terminology, to identify if they are able to make a **practical, detailed question** or if they should take a course, get a mentor or other type of help.

---

## Introduction to the original content

Here is the original content. It might be changed in a future revision to address concerns addressed directly in this post or on other posts.

### Original content

I have the intention take several actions some that could be done by using diamond moderator powers other that might be to create a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) as it could be required the support of a Community Manager. Here I am sharing in broad terms what I'm thinking.

The main goal is to help to increase the quality and helpfuness of Web Applicatons SE content.

I think that this will be reflected in a reduction of the number of questions having very low views (less than 10) and zero votes as they are intended to increase the chances that the posts will be found by users of search engines (Google, Bing, etc.) which are the main traffic source.

<sub>Questions related to low number of views / votes in Web Applications SE</sub>

> - [Is this site not running as well as it deserves?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/913/88163) from 2011
>   - [Is there a lack of voting on Web Applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1105/88163) from 2012
>   - [All 50 latest questions have score 0 or -1. Why do questions have such low scores on this Stack Exchange website?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4827/88163) from 2021
>   - [Very few views on my question?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4841/88163) from 2021
>   - [Decline of [gmail] and [facebook]: should we worry about this?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4881/88163) from 2023
>   - [Kind reminder, voting is Important!](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4889/88163) from 2023

Also I think that this will be reflected in a reduction of the number of questions of questions about administering / developing web applications.

The idea is to promote / encourage to search the help center of the web application corresponding to the question before asking a question and request people that already have posted questions that have low views, no positive score or have not answers to do the same.

They will be "required" to share what they "found and why it didn't meet their needs", as is already requested in the current version of [How to ask a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), so, this is doesn't imply a change in the Stack Exchange model, but it provides specific guidance both to askers and to reviewers.

IMHO this is something reasonable to be asked as all the major web applications have some sort of end-user official resources available at the fingertips of the users.

The specific form might vary, but there are industry best practices that might be mentioned, i.e. in the How to ask a good question help article and in the customizable elements of the Ask Question form (the specific wording of how to say this will be proposed later).
We could consider to include, a link to a FAQ with examples of the most relevant web apps, i.e.

Google Search

- [www.google.com](http://www.google.com): at the bottom has the link "How Search works"
- [www.google.com/search](http://www.google.com/search)? (search results page) at the botom has the link "Help", and the the sections have some way to point users to the help resources.

Facebook

- [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com): has links to the user help in several places. In the left panel has the link More > Help, In Account > Help and support.

Google Sheets, the web app having the top popular tag in Web Applications SE.

- https://sheets.google.com: Main menu > Help and feedback and when openinan a spreadsheet, the toolbar has a Help menu.

ChatGPT, hype during December and January

- https://chat.openai.com/chat, the left panel has the options OpenAI Discord and Updates and FAQ, and the bottom of the screen has a link to the release notes.

Some of the actions might be to encourage the community to contribute  to add the specific details of how to find each web application official resources for end-users in the corresponding tag wiki and / or in a canonical question, tag creators might be contacted to ask them to contribute with the creation of the tag wiki considering what was suggested above.

---

Web Applications [is the first site that graduated from Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched&page=11), but apparently other sites in the network have make take similar actions firsts:

From [Ryan's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357666/289691) to [What are the sites that allow questions without details and any research?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357580/289691)

> For example, [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [English Language Learners](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/466/120885) both ban questions that can be answered with a straightforward dictionary lookup (requiring you to explain why your define-this-word question cannot be answered that way).

Extracts from [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358586/289691) to [What are the sites that allow questions without details and any research?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357580/289691)

> - [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). [What does everyone mean by “insufficient research effort”?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8789/283469) from 2016
> - [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com). [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/865921), [How much research is considered as sufficient prior research before asking a question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13759/865921)
> - [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com). [How much research effort is expected of Ask Ubuntu users?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/11923/1163497), [What is the proper reaction to a post which clearly lacks research?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17568/1163497)
> - [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com). [What's happened to value in research effort?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2666/271999), [What qualifies as “research effort”?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5306/271999)
> - [Mathemathica & Wolfram Language](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). [Handling blatant RTFM cases---harmful to the community?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/274/76444), [The advisability of answering interesting questions for less-than-helpful users](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2122/76444)
> - [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/). [What is our criteria for a minimum effort?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2253/113400)

Super User is one of the sites created before Area 51. They also have some posts about research efforts like

> - [Close question for no reseach effort](https://meta.superuser.com/q/7829/152004)

#### Related from Meta Stack Exchange

- [How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177550/289691)
- [What parts of the help center can site moderators edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259914/289691)
- [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/289691)
- [What are the sites that allow questions without details and any research?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357580/289691)

#### Examples of requests to customize "How to ask" guidance

- Graphic Design [Updating the "How To Ask"](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3204/101026)
- Academia: [Customize the information window for the first-time askers](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4894/34261)
- Math Overflow [What should the modal window for first-time askers say?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5007)
- Code Golf: [Let's customise the "How to Answer" pop-up](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7070)

### Update

I have created several posts an tagged them using [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and [tour](/questions/tagged/tour) related to the site tour. The following post serves as "introduction" and table of contents:

[Please explain the Web Applications Tour in simple words](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4895/88163)

They are still *work in progress*.

---

### A bit of history

The how to ask questions and close reasons have evolved over the years

Here is one of old close reasons taken from [Disqus analogs? (comments platforms) [closed]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/10108/88163) (deleted, requires >10k rep) from December 2010.

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, visit the [help center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions).

The above question was discussed here. The symtoms of the question are that is the question title and body are practically the same and too short specially for nowadays quality filter minimal lenght.

[What does the community think about asking (and answering) really simple questions?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2442/88163) from 2013. The summary of this discussion is that the complexity of the question regarding difficulty of the task or the knowledge of the OP about the webapp are not relevant but if the answer is found searching the web by using a couple of keywords, then the question is not worthy to be posted on Web Applications SE.

Comment: Relevant meta discussion started by a community manager about whether we should mandate research on questions: [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584)

Answer (score 9):

Please don't do this Rubén. The goal of the website is this:

> we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about web applications.

We want answers about every question, even if there are already answers on the web out there.

We shouldn't close questions or delete them just because the answer is in the web app's documentation:

- The web app's documentation might not be clear or up-to-date or even correct
- The web app's documentation can't be upvoted, downvoted, edited, or commented on by the community
- The community might be able to provide an alternate answer that's even better than the web app's documentation
- The web app's documentation might have terrible SEO. Better to have the answer on Web Apps StackExchange as well, so that users can find it.
- The web app's documentation might not be licensed under Creative Commons BY-SA, which is a benefit to the community
- The web app's documentation might get deleted and links might get broken

This follows the general philosophy of Stack Exchange from its founding (to be like Wikipedia), and I see no reason to change it now.

Comment: The complete idea is the following :  `Web Applications is a question and answer site for power users of web applications. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about web applications.` As I already mentioned in another an answer your [self-answered-question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4951/88163), Stack Exchange doesn't work well with all kind of questions.

Comment: @Rubén It works well for the kind of questions that are being talked about here. Please listen to community feedback about this.

Answer (score 7):

I’m sorry but I have to respectfully disagree with what you’re suggesting. I believe that consistently implementing that will result in the closure of most questions on this site, as already lamented in the meta posts: [Do the moderators plan to close most questions on this site?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4984/7584) and [Is “needs details or clarity” connected to the help center article on questions that are automatically blocked for not meeting quality standards?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5008/7584) — among several other meta posts. It will also result in a further decrease in activity and participation due to stricter question requirements, and this site already has very low activity and participation for an SE site. I agree that we should and could encourage users to show research effort, but I don’t think mandating them to show research effort or else face question closure is a good idea.

> ### Purpose of this post
>
> While it's true that the tooltips of the upvote / downvote use the term "research effort" this term was used as shorthand to refer to a set of the oldest core rules. This oldest rules have synthetised in the help article [Why do I see a message that my question does not meet quality standards?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).

My understanding is that help center article is intended as a guidance for users whose questions were automatically blocked by the SE server. It is not an SE rule, policy, or close reason, and definitely not a “core rule”. I have raised this issue at the meta post: [Is “needs details or clarity” connected to the help center article on questions that are automatically blocked for not meeting quality standards?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5008/7584) The purpose of that help center article seems to be to assist users whose questions were automatically blocked by the SE server and who received a notification that their “question does not meet quality standards”. If a user posted their question succesfully and was not blocked, I don’t think that article applies to them.

> The spirit of "research effort" is actually about question be good fit according to topicality and audience. Users that are unfamiliar, before asking a question might have to spend time getting familiar with the topic in order to be able to write a question properly.
>
> In the specific case of Web Applications Stack Exchange people that are new to using a web application should spend time getting familiar with it before asking the question.

> They will be "required" to share what they "found and why it didn't meet their needs" […]

While I agree that “research effort” should be encouraged, **it should not be required or mandatory**. As I’ve stated above, this will result in the closure of most questions on this site; further driving down participation and activity on a site with an already low participation and activity. (A cursory look at questions on this site will reveal that most of them do not show research.)

Answer (score 1):

> I have the intention take several actions some that could be done by using diamond moderator power.

The community has already decided that there's no requirement to share what they "found and why it didn't meet their needs", see [Is showing research is a requirement when posting a question on WebApps SE?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4796/18147)

> I think that this will be reflected in a reduction of the number of questions having very low views (less than 10) and zero votes

There's already Roomba for removing questions having very low views, zero votes and no answers.

Also, showing research does not increase the number of views. E.g., look at my most viewed questions: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/18147/franck-dernoncourt?tab=questions&sort=views. Top 5:

1. 191k views: [How can I share my shopping cart with someone else on Amazon?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/59685/how-can-i-share-my-shopping-cart-with-someone-else-on-amazon)
2. 109k views: [How can I see Facebook notifications older than one week?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53784/how-can-i-see-facebook-notifications-older-than-one-week)
3. 72k views: [Where can I see all my comments on issues on GitHub?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103374/where-can-i-see-all-my-comments-on-issues-on-github)
4. 59k views: [How can I change my nationality in my PayPal account without having to open a new one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51005/how-can-i-change-my-nationality-in-my-paypal-account-without-having-to-open-a-ne)
5. 45k views: [How to find how many frames per second (FPS) a YouTube video has?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/71393/how-to-find-how-many-frames-per-second-fps-a-youtube-video-has)

My questions that don't mention any research attracted millions of visitors. Visitors don't care if the OP mentioned any research: visitors only care about getting the answer to the question.

> request people that already have posted questions that have low views, no positive score or have not answers to do the same.

A policy should apply to all users, not just a few ones. You are clearly targeting myself and perhaps a few others (since the vast majority of users who ask questions here simply dump one question, then go away).

> Other sites in the network have make take similar actions firsts:

As you've already read on https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357598/178179, the vast majority of SE sites does not require research.

> They will be "required" to share what they "found and why it didn't meet their needs.

How do you want the OP to share what they "found and why it didn't meet their needs? E.g., on [How can I view the channels that I have been added to recently on Slack?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/169569/18147), what do you want me to say? I searched the question on Google + looked at https://slack.com/help and didn't see any answers. So what do you want me to say in the question?

---

I looked at your 3 non-sheet-related questions to see how you share what you "found and why it didn't meet your needs. Here's my feedback:

[I want to try Google Classroom. How can I get access?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80534/18147):

> At the time that this question was posted I didn't found any other question about Google Classroom in Web Applications.

Who cares? Not surprising since Google Classroom had just been released then.

[Where can I find the Markdown syntax supported by StackEdit?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/98620/18147):

> At the time that this question was posted I didn't found any question about the above.

Again, who cares? That doesn't add anything to the question. Just clustering the space.

[URL to see all Google reviews for a local business](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/98203/18147): no "research" shared.

Comment: Thanks to bring these posts to my attention. They have being closed now. I even deleted one of my self answered questions.

Comment: @Rubén closing these questions won't help attract more visitors, on the contrary. Also, you'll have to close the majority of questions on WebApps: is that your plan? Lastly, what do you want me to say in the question to show research?

Comment: Dear readers: regarding  "The community has already decided... " please read my [answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4919/88163) to [How are we supposed to show one's research when posting a question?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4918/88163)

Comment: @Rubén "IMO showing research in the question body is not a requirement when posting a question on WebApps SE." was the most upvoted answer, so I thought it was the stance of the community. Anyway, how are we supposed to show one's research when posting a question? Example: [How can I view the channels that I have been added to recently on Slack?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/169569/18147) The question was closed because it doesn't show research. What should I say in the question to show my research? I'm genuinely trying to understand what I need to write in the questions.

Comment: Franck: The first statement in your comment is deceiving. The quote comes from the only answer, which only has a score 2. I'm sorry but I can't avoid to see that you maliciously are only quoting the part that is convinient to keep your position unchanged. Because of this, I'm sorry but I don't see that your behavior matches "genuinely trying to understand..."

Comment: @Rubén " I can't avoid to see that you maliciously are only quoting the part that is convinient to keep your position unchanged" -> [Tedinoz' answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4796/18147) has 2 components. Component 1:  research is not required. Component 2:  the question I used as an example was not closed because of lack of research. I agree a score of 2 isn't high. But that's the only answer I could find. (PS: I still would be interested to know [How are we supposed to show one's research when posting a question?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4918/18147)

Comment: _"IMO showing research in the question body is not a requirement when posting a question on WebApps SE." I authored the referenced post. Consider the context: it was the **ONLY** answer (question=12/2020, viewed 210 times), it received **2**  (two) votes, and was the "accepted answer". Could/should the opinions expressed be regarded as "the stance of the community". Unequivocally, no. At best it was the stance of three/four people and to suggest otherwise is both incorrect and inappropriate.

Comment: @Tedinoz I agree a score of 2 isn't high, but not many users look at this meta, and that's the only answer I could find.  "it was the ONLY answer" if anyone disagreed, they could've written their own answer. Also, note that most questions don't show research on Webapps, so I guess many users are fine with it.

Comment: "but not many users look at this meta..." So how could one possibly conclude that the post "was the stance of the community"? Nope, the fact of the matter is that a certain user has a problem with a certain moderator. Everything else is a distraction. There **are** [documented procedures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28869/399653) (upvoted by 170 votes and revised over time) for dealing with these issues and IMO it would be better for all concerned if the certain user simply cut to the chase and applied the established procedure(s).

Comment: @Tedinoz "note that most questions don't show research on Webapps, so I guess many users are fine with it." anyway from your link, the first step is "Make a post on the relevant per-site meta regarding the action taken" which I did (=the post we're commenting on), and I don't see the need to go further. We discuss, agree or disagree and move on. At that point, I think we're done discussing, but there remains the 2 follow-up questions: 1) Do we close the majority of questions on WebApps? 2) [How are we supposed to show one's research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4918/18147)

Comment: @Tedinoz (I'll post a separate question for 1 a bit later)